# Can “user view” include link to current user “recent”?

Tags: feature-request

Under "User", why is there no direct link for recent, like:

```
stackoverflow.com/users/recent/{userid}?Tab=Reputation&StartDate={today}&EndDate={today}
```

Only way I can find it, for this example is - I have bookmarked the page and click on the "today".

[image: http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/8472/exampley.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First click on #1, then on #2. (Even if #2 is already highlighted)

[image: Illustration of method]

To get to the page above simply click on the envelope next to your name on the top bar.
[image: link to recent]

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No, I meant - I can't find link to "recent", and this disturbs me.

Comment: @Marg, see my update.

Comment: Yes, ty.